# Selecting items from list A which are not in List B and vice versa

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list of `A` and `B` and trying to get elements from `A` which are not in `B` and from `B` which are not in `A`.

Below is my attempt to solve this.

```
var result = (List<string>)(from e in (A.Concat(B))
where !B.Contains(e) || !A.Contains(e)
select e);
```

And ran into below error..

> Unable to cast object of type
> WhereEnumerableIterator1[System.String] to type
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: Add `.ToList()` after your query to tell the query to convert the result into a list. You also don't need the `List<string>` cast

Comment: So basically an exclusive-or?  Items in A or B but not both?

Comment: Yes exclusive-or..

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate even though yours works if you either cal `ToList` or remove the cast to `List<string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding you cast error, the call should be like this.

```
var result = (from e in (A.Concat(B))
              where !B.Contains(e) || !A.Contains(e)
              select e).ToList();`
```

The ToList() method converts your LINQ query into a list.

Comment: Hmm.. My bad. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Except`:

```
List<int> firstList = new List<int> {1,2,3,4};

List<int> secondList = new List<int> { 1, 5 };

IEnumerable<int> res = secondList.Except(firstList).Concat(firstList.Except(secondList));

//Result => {5,2,3,4}
```

Comment: Just tried to solve this, saw S.Akbari's solution, tried it. It worked +1